# Accessing the properties of a super-class from an instance of its sub-class

Tags: java, inheritance, super

```
class Person {
    public String name;
    String id;

    public Person() {
        System.out.println("Parent default");
        name = id = "";
    }

    public Person(String name, String id) {
        System.out.println("Parent parameter");
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println(this.name + "\n" + this.id);
    }
}

class Student extends Person {

    Student() {}

    Student(String a, String b) {
        super(a, b);
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person p = new Person("A", "AA");
        Student s = new Student("b", "BB");
        s.show();
    }
}
```

I'm very new to java, so I wanted to understand a few basic things, but I failed. If I inherit from a parent class, this means I get a copy of the parent class in the child class, right? So, in this code—if I reference the parent class' `show` method (in Main class), this is supposed to show the parent class' `name` and `id` which were set previously.

But it isn't showing—so I have a problem in my understanding for sure. How can I access the parent class' copy from the child class? Using the `super` method from child's constructor? I also want to know the basic of inheritance in short.

Comment: You created a `Student` with the name "b" and the id "BB". The call to `show` prints these information. What did you expect and why?

Comment: But i called super(a,b) from Student(String a,String b) constructor.So,how can i print the parent class's name and id with the super keyword ?

Comment: with super(a,b) i'm calling parent's parameterized constructor - r8 ?

Comment: @inhaler its printing parents class value only. Student class inherited the method show. But you are passing different values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following statement:

```
Person p = new Person("A", "AA");
```

This is creating a `Person`. Its name is `"A"` and its id is `"AA"`.

Now consider this statement:

```
Student s = new Student("b", "BB");
```

This is creating a new `Student`. It's also creating a *new* `Person`. How is that possible? Well a `Student` *is* a `Person`. That's what inheritance means. When a type extends another type, that is defining an *"is a"* relationship between the types.

Dog extends Animal, because a Dog is an Animal. Car extends Vehicle, because a Car is a Vehicle.

So when you create a new `Student`, you're creating a `Person`. `Student extends Person`, so a `Student` is a `Person`. Not too surprisingly, I might add.

The `super` keyword is used to reference a parent class' methods and fields from its child class. In your `Student` constructor

```
Student(String a, String b) {
    super(a, b);
}
```

you're actually indirectly invoking the `Person` constructor by calling `super(a, b)`. So `new Student("b", "BB")` creates a `Person` with name `"b"` and id `"BB"`. That `Person` happens to be a `Student` as well.

There's no real relation whatsoever between person `"a"` and person `"b"` (though they could perhaps be distant cousins). If you ask person `"a"` for her name, she will reply `"a"`. If you ask person `"b"` for his name, he will reply `"b"`. It would be a little odd to have one person reply with someone else's name, so the individuals are treated as completely different people.

---

See also: [Java Inheritance Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: wow !! thank u . This clears the basic of  inheritance ^_^  @nbrooks

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance doesnt quite work how you think, The methods and variables are copied however the values are not.

If you make a new Person() and populate it, then make a new Student() the values in the Person are not copied, this is because values are usually based on Instances of classes not just Classes. There is a way to copy this but it is not usually done except in mistake which is to make the variable static.

Static variables are associated with the Class and not the instance and so are shared by all instances of that Class

When you call super() you are calling the method of the parent with the values of the child, so if you had two methods one overloaded and one not then you can call the parent method instead if you needed to, for instance, note it doesnt change the person class previously defined just sets the "parent" name variable in the Student

```
class Person{
    public Person(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }
}

class Student extends Person{
    public Student(String name, int grade){
        super(name);
        this.grade = grade;
    }
}
```

For the Static idea you can share a variable across all instances. ie

```
class Person{
   static String School = "Wandsworth Primary";
        public Person(String name) {
           this.name = name;
        }
    }

    class Student extends Person{
        public Student(String name, int grade){
            super(name);
            this.grade = grade;
        }

        public show() {
          System.out.println(school);
       }
    }
```

Comment: so, is there any way in my code i can call the parent's constructor from child class's constructor and get the parent's copy with the SUPER keyword ?

Comment: No, as its a different instance. Unless you declared the Parent variable static but then Every instance would have the same copy. I added an example to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Your child class, 'Student' has inherited the show method from the parent.

Hence, when you created an object of student, with some values b and BB, those values got displayed.

The values of the student , will be passed through student to parent since you called super(a,b) and will be displayed using the show() method which is obtained from it's parent class.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: so, is there any way in my code i can call the parent's constructor from child class's constructor and get the parent's copy with the SUPER keyword ?

Comment: You are already doing that. :) Student(String a,String b) is your child constructor. Inside it's body, you have written super(a,b). super(a,b) is actually calling Person(a,b). Hence b and BB are getting stored as the parent class' data member values.Hence it overrides the values a, AA that you assigned to parent first.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to inheritance. You just don't understand the concept of classes.

The `p` and `s` that you created are completely independent things. They won't affect each other, so calling `s.show()` will never print the values in `p`.

"But `s` inherits from `p` though! So it must have a copy of `p`!" you argued. No, `s` does not inherit from `p`, only `Student` inherits from `Person`.

It is not that `s` has a copy of `p`, but instead, `Student` has a copy of `Person`.

In `Student`, there isn't a `show` method, but you can still call it. Why? Because `Student` inherits from `Person`, so the `show` method is "copied" to `Student`.

When you call show, what actually happens is that the `show` in `Person` is called:

```
System.out.println(this.name + "\n" + this.id);
```

As you can see, it prints the caller's (We know it's caller because of the `this` keyword) name and id. So who's the caller here? `s`! That's why it prints the student's name and id.

If you still don't understand, just think of `Student` like this:

```
class Student {
    public String name;
    String id;

    void show() {
        System.out.println(this.name + "\n" + this.id);
    }    


    Student() {}

    Student(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println("Parent parameter");
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

See? I copied all the stuff from the `Person` class to `Student`!